# Vaginal fluid to heal cuts

Tags: vagina

yes this is a very weird question.

So i have noticed that when my girlfriend orgasms, and if im using my fingers and they happen to have a cut(we are both tested and clean), the cut heals super fast when covered in her orgasm fluid (im talking about hours, so its really fast).

My question is, why does this happen? What is the substance responsible for the healing? Can this property be used in the medical field somehow?

Comment: `yes this is a very weird question.`

Actually, it's not. It's an unfortunately common question in many ways. Your girlfriend's vaginal secretions are generally very hospitable to human tissue for obvious reasons, so they at least don't irritate or prolong the healing of your minor cuts and abrasions. Personally, I'm extremely skeptical that they actually do much of anything other than no harm and make you feel good.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, Donsa! It might be helpful for you to take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially [ask]. Aside from your observation, that makes the question "unweird": What has your prior research revealed to you so far?